# Tasks not being processed as they complete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am stuck trying to process the results from a number of database queries as they become available. Right now they are all handled at the same time.

There is a list of clients (about 40 right now) each has a database of it's own and they need all need to be queried (Using EF-6). The query method on the repository returns a Task. These tasks are created in a loop.

```
public Task<List<Employee>> FindByNameOrBirthDateAsync(string surName, DateTime? birthDate)
    {
        var query = ApplicationContext.Employees
            .Include(e => e.Address)
            .Include(e => e.CorporateEntities);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(surName))
            query = query.Where(e => e.Surname == surName);

        if (birthDate != null)
            query = query.Where(e => e.BirthDate == birthDate);

        return query.ToListAsync();
    }
```

This code is being called by a service that in turn is being called by a Web-API controller.

```
public class SearchService
{
    public List<Task<List<Employee>>> SearchOverAllClients(List<Client> clients, string surName, DateTime? birthDate)
    {
        return clients.Select(client => FindEmployees(client.Id, surName, birthDate)).ToList();
    }

    private Task<List<Employee>> FindEmployees(int clientId, string surname, DateTime? birthDate)
    {
        ApplicationUoW unit = new ApplicationUoW(clientId);

        return unit.Employees.FindByNameOrBirthDateAsync(surname, birthDate);

    }
}
```

In the controller Task.WhenAny() is supposed to return the results to the client as they become available and write them to the output stream.

I have tested with Fiddler breaking on each iteration and the results are sent one at a time. So I don't think the issue is in the stream writing code.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]string surname = "", [FromUri]DateTime? birthDate = null)
    {
        List<Client> clients = _clientsService.GetClients();
        List<Task<List<Employee>>> tasks = _searchService.SearchOverAllClients(clients, surname, birthDate);

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();

        response.Content = new PushStreamContent(
            async (outputStream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    while (tasks.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
                        tasks.Remove(task);

                        List <Employee> employees = await task;
                        string responseContent =
                            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }));

                        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseContent);

                        await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
                catch (HttpException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == -2147023667)
                {
                    //The remote host closed the connection.
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    outputStream.Close();
                }
            });

        return response;
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it waits for all tasks to be finished before the results are handled. While I want to handle them as soon as they are ready.

I have been trying multiple variations of this code with different uses of aysnc/await however all attempts have been unsuccessful so far.

**Update**
I have removed the unneeded parallel code as per the suggestions in the comments.

Comment: umm, `List<T>` is not thread safe, you can't call `Add` from inside a Parallel.Foreach without doing some kind of locking.

Comment: "Parallel" database queries are typically *slower* from one query that loads the required data in one roundtrip. That's because the main delay is caused by network latency. If not, you should be looking at optimizing your indexes, or check for N+1 problems. BTW parallel loading of individual entities *is* an N+1 problem

Comment: The real throughput killer though is that you increase contention and locking by the number of concurrent connections. You could cause some ugly deadlocks this way

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The reason we are using parallel queries is because we are querying different databases (with the same schema). That could be on different physical servers.

Comment: `Parallel` is unsuitable because you don't have any data to process in parallel, you have tasks and steps. You can collect all asynchronous tasks in an array and use `Task.WhenAll`, or even use `clients.Select(client=>Find...)` to pass an IEnumerable<Task> to `WhenAll`. That will wait for all results before proceeding.

Comment: Another option is to write an async method that calls and processes each database response, and combine them all with `WhenAll`

Comment: The best option though, is probably to use a TPL dataflow to break the entire processing in pipeline steps. The first step could call each DB and pass the data to the next step. A DOP of eg 5 would allow you to hit 4 dbs at a time. Downstream steps would run in their own threads, with appropriate DOP and input limits to prevent overloading

Comment: "use WhenAll. That will wait for all results before proceeding" That is the issue here I am using WhenAny so the code should proceed as soon as it gets the first response. However it waits for all results.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks, I updated it to a ConcurrentBag<T>. That should be thread safe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130229/discussion-between-arnold-wiersma-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: @ArnoldWiersma No, you should not use `ConcurrentBag`.  Rather, there's no reason at all to start all of the tasks using `Parallel.ForEach`.  Just use a regular `foreach` or, as has been mentioned before, `Select` from LINQ.  Creating new threads just to start asynchronous operations is actively *counter* productive.

Comment: @Servy You are right. I've been at this for too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

ASP.NET implements the `SynchronizationContext` in a way that guarantees `async` code will run on a single thread (but not necessarily the same thread) at any given time throughout execution. That means that the code you have posted right now will all be run on a single thread. So for example, if all the query tasks completed immediately, the callback code after `var task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks)` would not be run in parallel - each callback would be run synchronously, one by one.

By converting to: `await Task.WhenAny(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false)` you're telling .NET that the callback code can be run on a threadpool thread. But then you'll have to make sure the code after that `await` is thread-safe and doesn't require the context.

If you're not already familiar with SynchronizationContext and why it matters when using `async/await`, here's an article I found to be helpful:
[Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/)